# reading data from a memory

Tags: verilog, memory

I have written the code to read data from the memory as follows:

```
module memcode(clk1,we,dout);

reg [7:0] add = 8'b00000000;
reg [7:0] din;
input we,clk1;
integer i=0;
output [7:0] dout;
reg [7:0] dout;
reg [7:0] data;
wire [7:0] douta;
//assign data = dout;

always @ (posedge clk1) begin
  if (we == 1) begin
    if (i < 255) begin
      data <= din;
      add = add+1;
      i = i+1;
      dout = data;
      //dout = douta;
    end
  end
end

bram8 u1 (
  .clka(clk1),
  .wea(we),      // Bus [0 : 0] 
  .addra(add),   // Bus [7 : 0] 
  .dina(din),    // Bus [7 : 0] 
  .douta(dout)); // Bus [7 : 0] 

endmodule
```

However I am getting the errors:

```
ERROR:HDLCompilers:246 - "memcode.v" line 55 Reference to vector reg 'dout' is not a legal net lvalue
ERROR:HDLCompilers:102 - "memcode.v" line 55 Connection to output port 'douta' must be a net lvalue
```

When I run check syntax I am not getting any error however when I try to synthesize I get the above errors.
Can anyone please help me where am I going wrong?

Comment: You haven't even told us what processor this code is supposed to run on, what language it is in, and there are no comments explaining what you *think* it is supposed to do.  -1 for a poorly asked question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - it's tagged with Verilog. You're not trying very hard.

Comment: @trygvis: I didn't notice the tag, but this really should be stated in the question itself.  It also doesn't excuse the irresponsible lack of comments.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It gives HDL compiler errors, I realize your frustration but please be a bit nicer with the comments.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with the source code. If you draw the block diagram that it represents, the problems become obvious:

- `din` has no source
- `dout` has *two* sources
- `i` is never initialized

In fact, it's so messed up, it really isn't clear what your true intent was. If this module was supposed to represent a read-only memory, why does it have a `we`? And if it has a `we`, why doesn't it have a data input bus?

Answer (score 1):

No time to scan through in detail right now, but try changing douta to a `reg`, and use all non-blocking assignments (i.e. `<=`) in your always block.
Also check the documentation for the bram8 module and how it's meant to be used (e.g. what inputs it expects, etc)

Comment: @ Oli Glaser: I have tried as u said but ISE is showing the same error.. I have written the code after going through datasheet of LogiCORE IP Block Memory Generator v4.2..

Comment: Okay, sorry didn't have time to look properly last night. I would upgrade to the latest version of the core. What device are you using - I have recently used the BRAM generator in a Spartan-3A, so if you can send me your module (email on my profile page) I can figure it out for you if you like.